# Fast way to rasterize a grid of points/pixels

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl, gpgpu, raster

I want to fill the screen with a grid of points. My desired performance would be about the same speed as drawing that many pixels as a contiguous quad (or equivalent triangle clipped with glViewport). Using `GL_POINT` primitives (positioned via gl_VertexID, not attribs) or `glPolygonStipple` are possibilities, but are still a little slower. Here's an example of what I want (though the black points drawn may be yet more sparse):

[image]

Are there any other methods to draw this grid? 
(*in a similar time to a smaller quad of the same number of pixels*)

Wouldn't it be great if the rasterizer was programmable!

The main point of this is to be able to **write to both stencil and colour buffers** in this grid pattern from a fragment shader.

---

*EDIT*

**Some rendering times:**

Full screen for me is 1680x1050, GTX670. Times are calculated drawing 10,000 times each frame, no depth test. I draw a quad with a big triangle and clip using glViewport.

- Rendering a full screen quad and calling discard for `coord%4>0`: 0.112ms
- Rendering a full screen quad, assigning const colour: 0.059ms
- Rendering with `glPolygonStipple` creating `%4` pattern: 0.009ms
- Rendering quarter full screen quad: 0.003ms
- Rendering a 1x1 quad: 0.002ms (binding VBO and shader, could prob be optimized)

The differences get larger with a more sparse grid, for example `%16`.

---

*EDIT*

OK, I've thrown together a small example. Requires `glut` and `glew` libraries:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define RESOLUTION_X 1680
#define RESOLUTION_Y 1050
#define USE_32_BIT 0
#define TEST_LOOP 1000 //number of quads to draw per frame
#define WARMUP_MS 1000 //time between switching methods
#define TEST_MS 4000 //time to benchmark for
#define TESTS 6
#define DRAW_GRAPH 1
#define SCALE_MS 0.2f //for drawing the graph


GLuint fbo, colourTex, vbo, shader, shaderPoints, shaderDiscard;
int viewport[2];
int test = 0;
int results_time[TESTS];
int results_frames[TESTS];

float colours[TESTS][3] = {
    {1,0,0},
    {1,1,0},
    {1,0,1},
    {0,1,0},
    {0,1,1},
    {0,0,1},
    };

const char* names[TESTS] = {
    "full",
    "full discard",
    "full stipple",
    "draw points",
    "quarter",
    "one"
    };

float triangleVerts[9] = {-1,-1,0,-1,4,0,4,-1,0};

const char* vertexShaderSrc = "#version 150\nin vec4 v;\nvoid main() {gl_Position = v;}\n";
const char* vertexShaderPointsSrc = "#version 150\nuniform ivec2 s;\nvoid main() {ivec2 p = ivec2(gl_VertexID%(s.x/4),gl_VertexID/(s.x/4)); gl_Position = vec4(2.0*(p*4+0.5)/s-1.0, 0, 1);}\n";
const char* fragmentShaderSrc = "#version 150\nout vec4 c;\nvoid main() {c = vec4(1,0,0,1);}\n";
const char* fragmentShaderDiscardSrc = "#version 150\nout vec4 c;\nvoid main() {if (int(gl_FragCoord.x)%4>0||int(gl_FragCoord.y)%4>0) discard; c = vec4(1,0,0,1);}\n";

void setupDraw(GLuint program, int x, int y)
{
    glUseProgram(program);
    glViewport(0, 0, x, y);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    GLuint loc = glGetAttribLocation(program, "v");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(loc);
    glVertexAttribPointer(loc, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
}

void polygonStippleGrid(int x, int y)
{
    unsigned char tilePattern[32*32];
    memset(tilePattern, 0, sizeof(tilePattern));
    for (int j = 0; j < 32; j += y)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i += x)
        {
            int index = (j * 32 + i);
            tilePattern[index / 8] |= 1 << (index % 8);
        }
    }
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glPolygonStipple(tilePattern);
}

void display()
{
    static int lastTime = -1;
    int elapsed = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);
    if (lastTime == -1) lastTime = elapsed;
    int dt = elapsed - lastTime;
    lastTime = elapsed;

    static int warmup = WARMUP_MS + 2000;
    static int running = TEST_MS;
    warmup -= dt;
    if (warmup <= 0 && test < TESTS)
    {
        running -= dt;
        results_time[test] += dt;
        results_frames[test] += 1;
        if (running <= 0)
        {
            printf("%s %s %.6fms\n", names[test], USE_32_BIT?"rgba32":"rgba8", results_time[test]/(float)(results_frames[test] * TEST_LOOP));
            test += 1;
            warmup = WARMUP_MS;
            running = TEST_MS;
        }
    }

    #if DRAW_GRAPH
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    glViewport(0, 0, viewport[0], viewport[1]);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    float s = 2.0f / TESTS;
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    for (int i = 0; i < TESTS; ++i)
    {
        if (!results_frames[i]) continue;
        glColor3fv(colours[i]);
        float x = -1.0f + 2.0f * i / (float)TESTS;
        float y = -1.0f + 2.0f * (results_time[i]/(float)(results_frames[i] * TEST_LOOP)) / SCALE_MS;
        glVertex2f(x, -1.0f); glVertex2f(x, y); glVertex2f(x + s, y); glVertex2f(x + s, -1.0f);
    }
    glEnd();
    #endif

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);

    switch (test)
    {
    case 0: //straight full screen quad
        setupDraw(shader, RESOLUTION_X, RESOLUTION_Y);
        for (int i = 0; i < TEST_LOOP; ++i)
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        break;
    case 1: //full screen quad, discarding pixels in the frag shader
        setupDraw(shaderDiscard, RESOLUTION_X, RESOLUTION_Y);
        for (int i = 0; i < TEST_LOOP; ++i)
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        break;
    case 2: //using polygon stipple to mask out fragments
        polygonStippleGrid(4, 4);
        glEnable(GL_POLYGON_STIPPLE);
        setupDraw(shader, RESOLUTION_X, RESOLUTION_Y);
        for (int i = 0; i < TEST_LOOP; ++i)
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        glDisable(GL_POLYGON_STIPPLE);
        break;
    case 3: //drawing points, but computing the position in the vertex shader
        glUseProgram(shaderPoints);
        glUniform2i(glGetUniformLocation(shaderPoints, "s"), RESOLUTION_X, RESOLUTION_Y);
        for (int i = 0; i < TEST_LOOP; ++i)
            glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, (RESOLUTION_X/4)*(RESOLUTION_Y/4));
        break;
    case 4: //a quad one quarter of the screen (as a speed comparison)
        setupDraw(shader, RESOLUTION_X / 4, RESOLUTION_Y / 4);
        for (int i = 0; i < TEST_LOOP; ++i)
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        break;
    case 5: //a 1x1 quad (as a speed comparison)
        setupDraw(shader,1, 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < TEST_LOOP; ++i)
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        break;
    default: break;
    }
    glUseProgram(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0); //HACK: assumes location is always zero
    //printf("%i %i %i\n", test, warmup, running);

    glFinish();
    glutSwapBuffers();
    glutPostRedisplay();

    assert(glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR);
}

void reshape(int x, int y)
{
    viewport[0] = x;
    viewport[1] = y;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    memset(results_time, 0, sizeof(results_time));
    memset(results_frames, 0, sizeof(results_frames));

    //init glut
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutCreateWindow("quadtest");
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    glewInit();

    //init gl stuff
    glGenTextures(1, &colourTex);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, colourTex);
    #if USE_32_BIT
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, RESOLUTION_X, RESOLUTION_Y, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
    #else
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, RESOLUTION_X, RESOLUTION_Y, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
    #endif

    /*
    GLuint stencilRB;
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &stencilRB);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, stencilRB);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL, RESOLUTION_X, RESOLUTION_Y);
    */

    glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, colourTex, 0);
    //glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, stencilRB);
    assert(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(triangleVerts), triangleVerts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLuint v = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint vp = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint f = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    GLuint fd = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(v, 1, &vertexShaderSrc, NULL);
    glShaderSource(vp, 1, &vertexShaderPointsSrc, NULL);
    glShaderSource(f, 1, &fragmentShaderSrc, NULL);
    glShaderSource(fd, 1, &fragmentShaderDiscardSrc, NULL);

    GLint ok = GL_TRUE;
    shader = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shader, v);
    glAttachShader(shader, f);
    glLinkProgram(shader);
    glGetProgramiv(shader, GL_LINK_STATUS, &ok);
    assert(ok == GL_TRUE);

    /*
    char log[512];
    int n;
    glGetShaderInfoLog(v, 512, &n, log);
    printf("%s\n", log);
    glGetProgramInfoLog(shader, 512, &n, log);
    printf("%s\n", log);
    */

    shaderPoints = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderPoints, vp);
    glAttachShader(shaderPoints, f);
    glLinkProgram(shaderPoints);
    glGetProgramiv(shaderPoints, GL_LINK_STATUS, &ok);
    assert(ok == GL_TRUE);

    shaderDiscard = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderDiscard, v);
    glAttachShader(shaderDiscard, fd);
    glLinkProgram(shaderDiscard);
    glGetProgramiv(shaderDiscard, GL_LINK_STATUS, &ok);
    assert(ok == GL_TRUE);

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    assert(glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR);

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Interestingly, using `GL_RGBA32F` 32 bit colour impacts performance a fair bit, also bringing back the overhead of the discard method to approximately the same as a full screen quad. The `glPolygonStipple` method gives dramatic improvements in this case, more so than with 8 bit. There is a discrepancy with the previous `glPolygonStipple` result too, I can reproduce both and haven't narrowed down the difference yet.

output for `GL_RGBA`:

```
full rgba8 0.059ms
full discard rgba8 0.112ms
full stipple rgba8 0.050ms
draw points rgba8 0.079ms
quarter rgba8 0.004ms
one rgba8 <0.001ms
```

output for `GL_RGBA32F`:

```
full rgba32 0.240ms
full discard rgba32 0.241ms
full stipple rgba32 0.101ms
draw points rgba32 0.091ms
quarter rgba32 0.015ms
one rgba32 <0.001ms
```

Drawing points and positioning from `gl_VertexID` will beat `glPolygonStipple` for `GL_RGBA32F`. I'd assume this trend would carry on for more expensive shaders (or at least memory-intensive).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scattered memory writes of a sparse grid may simply mean more overhead that can't be avoided.

1. Draw `GL_POINT`s
2. Use `glPolygonStipple`
3. Initialize the stencil buffer with the pattern for a masking a full screen quad

What ever you do **do not use the `discard` method if the fragment shader is expensive**<sup>[1]</sup>. This is really stupid because you clog the pipeline with many threads which don't do anything.

<sub>[1] Either takes a long time to execute or uses lots of registers or local memory</sub>

Comment: This. Even if you end up using the shader method (which I really like, because the customizing options are endless), use `step()` instead. Because 1: Branches on the GPU are bad and slow (some devices like the Samsung Galaxy Tabs will just crash on your face with no error), 2: discards are slow.

Answer (score 3):

> Are there any other methods to draw this grid?

Exactly this grid? Well in that case your grid has a periodicity of 4 and an offset of -1 in x and -2 in y direction. So the fragment shader to produce it (discarding the "black" pixels) would be

```
void main() 
{
    if( ((gl_FragPosition.x-1) % 4) == 0 && ((gl_FragPosition.y-2) % 4) == 0 )
        discard;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1,1,1,1);
}
```

Setting the stencil op to always replace the stencil value, will set the stencil buffer to your `ref` value everywhere, where no pixels are discarded.

If you can't express your grid by some kind of formula, well, use a texture instead.

Comment: I'm specifically after something that's very fast. This will require a **full screen quad** (and I assume very similar in performance to `glPolygonStipple`) which is a fair amount **slower** than a smaller quad in which I could simply scale `gl_FragCoord.xy` to get the grid coordinates - unfortunately in this case I cannot write stencil values to the desired position.

Comment: @jozxyqk: A single full screen quad is child's play for a GPU. Seriously it will take the GPU more time to setup the drawing process, than to perform the actual rasterization of a single quad.

Comment: I believe this is incorrect. A full screen quad may be pretty fast if you only do it once. However, it is by no means faster (in fact orders of magnitude slower) than the setup time. There are much higher res screens than mine out there. See the edit

Comment: @jozxyqk: You didn't show the code you used for the benchmark. Benchmarking OpenGL operations can be tricky, because OpenGL operations are performed asynchronously, so you must use fences or sync objects to get accurate data.

Comment: Very simple. I draw a quad 10,000 times in a for loop in my display function. I draw using a standard mainloop with SDL_GL_SwapBuffers at the end. No vsync enabled at the driver level. No need for an explicit sync. Time/frames is averaged and divided by 10,000 every few seconds. If you find different relative results, please post :)

Comment: @jozxyqk: A code example is worth a thousand words. There are a lot of intricate details that can be done wrong.

Comment: I don't have time to throw together an example right now, but I'll post something shortly. Am I right in assuming you think I've made a mistake and my timings are wrong or not characteristic of the operations? i.e. are you expecting something different and if so what?

Comment: @jozxyqk: Indeed I do. As I already wrote: OpenGL operates asynchronously to actually timing operations is a bit tricky. A lot of the runtime timing behavior of OpenGL defeats common sense.

Comment: Well, there's your standalone example (see the edit). Pretty similar results to my previous tests.

Comment: @jozxyqk: It's even worse than I suspected: The way you're timing the iteration time will not just measure the time required for a quad to draw. It also includes the whole buffer swap and the GLUT event loop iteration. The numbers you have, are tainted with a lot of dirt.

Comment: Clearly you've missed the great big for(... 1000 ...) loop. The overhead of all the other stuff is completely insignificant. Try commenting out the switch statement and see what times you get then :). If you're really worried make it 10,000 or 100,000. This is a pretty basic method for accurate benchmarking. Certainly attempting to measure single operations as I think you assumed I was doing produces a lot of noise.

Comment: @jozxyqk: That big 1000 loop I didn't miss. But the only thing that loop does is queueing up a lot of drawing commands, that will get executed *sometime* between the end of the loop, the call of SwapBuffers and the next drawing operation. There are a lot of unknowns between. If you want to measure the drawing time alone, you must embrace the loop in a fence and wait for the completion of the drawing commands by putting a sync on the fence, _before_ you even call SwapBuffers. Like I told, naively putting a timing somewhere can be misleading. Look for `glFenceSync` and how to use it.

Comment: Also calling glDrawArrays with a short batch size in a loop adds all the overhead of a glDrawArrays call. To measure the time it takes to draw 1000 triangles you want to do one since glDrawArrays call that batches 1000 triangles, instead of doing 1000 glDrawArrays calls that batch 1 triangle each. Doing the later you mostly measuring the time it takes to call glDrawArrays, not the time it takes to draw a triangle.

Comment: `glFinish` will accomplish the same thing with less effort. I'll even throw it before `glutSwapBuffers` and you can see the timing results remain **exactly the same**. I believe telling glut to swap the buffers ends up causing a sync over multiple frames. I don't know if it's glut that does this or if it's handled at the driver level. Point is that all the jobs I give the GPU should finish before drawing the next frame. The draw loop can't just go wild and send thousands of frames worth of draw calls, that'd create some insane lag and queues would get very large.

Comment: No, I do want to include the time taken to call `glDrawArrays`, that's the point. When I draw a quad with size 1x1 that's my way of excluding the rasterization and fragment shading time. When I do the exact same thing, but make the quad fill the whole frame I can calculate the difference to find the actual time taken to rasterize to the rest of the screen.

Comment: @jozxyqk: This methods does not measure the time it takes to rasterize the whole screen, because the fillrate is not proportional to the screensize occupied by a quad. If you want to make an accurate comparision between a 1×1 pixel quad to a full screen quad, you *must* get that glDrawArrays overhead out of the way, because that will largely skew the result. The correct way to go about this would be to have an array of 10000 quads, each screen pixel aligned (that should be 4×4 pixels at least, because that's the block size today's GPUs operate on at least).

Comment: @jozxyqk: And then compare this with the time it takes to rasterize a full screen quad. Effectively what you want to do is performing a so called *differential measurement*. They key point is: You want to measure the fill rate, nothing else. That glDrawArrays call (and glFinish as well, BTW) introduce unknown dirt effects, that result in a significant, unknown systematic error. You want to do your measurements in a way, that the systematic error cancels out between those measurements. I'm a trained experimental physicist and a large part of the studies involve, how to do measurements right.

Comment: @jozxyqk: measuring OpenGL timings is not so much different from measuring time of flights in a particle accelerator, where the only signal you have are some induces charge influences on a capacitor, that arrive with some delay and which get skewed by the electrical fields used to control the ion beam. Or if you want to measure very small variations of electrical current in an experiment. It always remains the same principle. Anyway, I'm right now modifying your program to deliver an accurate measurement.

Comment: My target application is not to actually draw 10,000 quads from the same draw call. Either way I believe the results will be quite similar. To get back to the point... I'm showing at a 500x slowdown from 1x1 to 1680x1050 which is fairly definitive: a full screen quad *is* in fact quite slow and using `discard` seems to only hurt performance. Also the setup time appears to be ~1/23 of the full screen quad drawing time (moving `setupDraw` into the loops).